# Angularjs ngRoute is not working in firefox

Tags: angularjs, single-page-application, angular-routing

```js
<script>
        var app = angular.module('singlepageapp', ['ngRoute'])

        app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider

                .when('/About', {
                    templateUrl: 'DistrictMaps/About.aspx',
                })
            .when('/Ch', {
                templateUrl: 'DistrictMaps/Ch.aspx',

            })

        }]);
        app.run(function ($rootScope) {
            $rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function () {
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $("#bottom").offset().top,
                }, 2000);
            });
        });
    </script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js">
<body ng-app="singlepageapp">

    <div id="svgdiv" style="text-align: left;">
        <svg
            preserveAspectRatio='xMinYMin'
            viewBox="0 0 850 700"
            width="850"
            height="700"
            id="Main_svg"
            version="1.1">
            <g
                inkscape:groupmode="layer"
                id="layer3"
                inkscape:label="innercircle">

                <a href="#/About" id="94650dac-e76b-4dec-8fcc-2d40dff7d95d" class="District" title="EastGodavari">
                    <path

                        d="m 457.26279,328.23151 -0.18711,1.35614 0.2804,1.16955 0.14073,1.44995 -0.56132,1.02936 -0.82253,0.94834 2.05818,-0.13327 0.92968,-0.73031 2.39029,-0.53094 0.79641,-0.86304 2.39029,-1.32788 1.59388,-0.19937 1.65945,-1.06241 2.12482,-1.52724 2.45692,-0.99578 1.65998,0.19937 1.79272,0.73031 2.52302,-1.26178 1.06188,-0.46484 1.39451,-1.26125 1.85935,-0.99577 1.39398,-0.0666 0.86358,-0.99577 1.79272,-0.73031 0.7964,0.53094 0.73031,-1.26178 1.99209,-0.66367 1.06241,-0.66421 1.46061,-1.26124 1.39451,0.3321 0.92914,-0.99631 2.05872,-0.53094 1.65945,-0.99577 0.33211,-0.92968 2.19145,-0.53147 0.13273,-0.79641 1.52672,-0.59757 1.32788,0.53094 1.59388,0.3982 0.99578,-1.26124 0.46483,-1.19515 0.99578,-0.46484 0.46484,-0.7303 -0.19937,-0.92968 -0.46431,-0.53094 0.66368,-1.46061 0.19937,-0.92968 -0.19937,-1.06241 -1.39452,0 -0.33157,-0.3982 0.59758,-1.26178 0.7303,-0.0661 1.32788,-0.266 0.59758,-0.66367 0.53093,-1.65999 0.0666,-1.06241 -0.46484,-1.19514 -0.59757,-0.53094 -1.12851,-0.66421 -0.26601,-1.19514 0.39874,-1.39451 0.73031,-0.59758 0.92967,-0.59757 0.19884,-0.86304 0,-1.52671 0.26547,-0.66421 0.19937,-1.39451 -0.39821,-1.12851 1.19515,-0.92968 0.3982,-1.52725 -0.26547,-1.19514 -0.13273,-1.59335 0.53094,-0.99578 -0.46484,-1.26178 -0.66367,-1.26124 0.13273,-0.53147 -0.99578,-0.99578 -0.79694,-0.73031 -0.19937,-1.12904 -1.46061,-0.99578 -0.79694,-0.3982 -0.59757,1.12851 -0.13274,0.86304 -0.13273,1.39452 0.73031,1.06241 0.39873,0.86304 0.92914,0.79694 0.59758,0.26547 0,1.52725 -0.59758,0.59757 0.0666,0.86304 0.19937,0.99578 -0.13327,1.12904 -0.92914,-0.13274 -1.52725,-0.6642 -1.79272,-0.0661 -0.86304,-0.46484 -0.99631,-0.99631 -0.59757,-0.86304 0.0666,-1.12851 1.32788,-0.13274 0.66421,-0.86357 0.13273,-1.39398 -0.26547,-1.12904 0.59758,-0.79641 -0.0666,-0.99631 -0.79694,-0.92914 0.266,-1.46115 0.92915,-1.26125 1.46061,-1.65998 1.46115,-0.73031 0.7303,-1.59334 0.53094,-1.39452 2.98786,-1.52724 1.39452,-1.65999 1.19514,-0.92914 0.99578,-0.92967 2.09923,-0.43925 1.12051,-1.21701 0.99312,-1.05654 1.05654,-0.89663 1.02456,-0.99257 1.79325,-0.44832 1.02457,-1.08906 2.11362,-1.47287 -1.06028,-0.98139 -1.45368,-0.64608 -1.29216,0.16152 0,-0.96912 0.24201,-0.80814 0.56559,-1.21113 0.0805,-0.88863 0.96966,0 1.04961,-0.96913 0.96913,-0.8076 -0.48456,-1.53471 -0.80761,-1.13117 0.081,-1.29217 0.32304,-0.8076 0.8076,-1.05015 0.88863,-1.04962 1.29217,-0.96965 0.96912,-1.93825 -1.53471,-1.29216 0,-1.05015 -1.04962,-0.8076 -0.56559,-1.2927 -0.96912,-0.96912 -1.53471,0.8076 -1.53471,0.40407 -0.72711,0.64608 -1.29216,-0.16152 -0.40354,-0.96912 -0.16152,-1.21167 -1.05015,-0.88863 -0.40406,1.13117 -0.32305,0.72658 -0.96912,0.72711 -0.081,0.72711 0.081,1.21113 -0.88863,1.05015 -1.29216,0.24255 -1.53471,-0.32304 -0.64608,-0.88863 -0.96913,-0.24255 -0.40406,-1.13064 0,-1.21167 -1.37319,0.24255 -0.64609,0.72711 -0.72657,-0.16152 -0.64662,-1.37319 -0.88809,0.64608 0,-1.21167 0,-1.69623 1.04961,-0.88863 0.56559,-0.56506 0,-1.69623 -0.56559,-0.88863 -1.77672,0.64608 -1.21167,-1.13064 -0.72711,-1.21167 -0.96912,-0.72657 -1.37319,-0.32305 -0.96912,0.32305 -0.32304,-1.21167 -0.8881,-0.56559 -1.2927,0.24254 -0.72711,0.56559 -0.96912,1.45369 -1.69623,0.64608 -1.37266,-0.32304 -1.37319,-1.37319 -0.72711,-1.69623 -0.8076,-0.8881 -1.29216,-0.16152 -1.93878,0.16152 -0.96912,0.96912 -0.24255,0.48456 -1.29216,0.0805 -0.96913,0.64661 -0.56558,0.80761 -0.64609,0.88809 -0.88809,-1.04962 -0.24255,-1.37319 0.56559,-1.6152 1.04962,-1.93878 0.7271,-1.6152 0,-1.77726 -0.88862,-1.04962 -0.0805,-1.05015 -1.13064,-0.64608 -0.40407,-0.96965 -1.77726,-0.32304 -1.45368,1.05014 -0.24201,1.13065 -1.21167,0.40407 -1.21167,-0.16152 -1.37319,0 -1.37319,-0.48457 -0.96913,0.80761 -0.96912,-0.40407 0.0805,-1.13064 1.13118,-1.45369 1.21114,-1.53471 1.53471,-0.56559 1.21167,-1.13064 0.88863,-0.64608 2.01927,-0.24255 1.13064,-1.53418 1.05015,-1.37319 0.88863,-0.72711 0.48456,-1.05015 0.24201,-1.6152 0.88863,-0.64608 0.40354,-1.29216 -0.16152,-1.61574 0.081,-0.96912 -1.45368,-0.88863 -0.32357,-1.77673 -1.04962,-1.61574 -0.8076,-0.96912 -1.05921,0.0517 -0.42273,0.65354 -0.4611,0.38435 -1.19142,0.1919 -0.88383,0.46111 -0.96059,0.5384 -0.76869,0.15353 -1.1525,0.11514 -0.76869,0.42272 -0.30758,0.88384 -0.69193,0 -1.26817,0.15405 -0.69139,0.26867 -0.38435,0.65355 -0.38434,0.34596 -1.07574,-0.0773 -1.07627,0.11568 -1.03735,0.61463 -0.88383,1.07627 -0.53841,0.42272 -0.61463,0.26867 -1.15303,1.03789 -0.38434,0.49949 0.76815,0.39927 0.51921,0.22762 0.6173,0.77935 0.48723,0.58478 0.68179,0.45471 0.68233,0.48669 0.0325,0.68233 -0.35769,0.6818 -0.42219,0.45471 -0.55173,0.68233 -0.55226,0.35716 -1.07201,0.19457 -0.97392,0.13007 -0.84491,0.0325 -0.77935,-0.0976 -0.77935,0.6173 -0.38968,0.61729 -0.6818,0.58425 -0.68233,0.38967 -0.22708,0.71485 0,0.6818 -0.32518,0.35716 -0.38967,0.58477 -0.81187,0.0325 -1.03949,0.32464 -1.16902,0.19511 -1.10399,-0.32518 -1.07201,0.35769 -0.74683,0.25961 -0.0976,0.55226 -0.42219,0.81187 -0.81187,0.68179 -0.84438,0.26014 -0.77935,-0.0975 -0.56079,0.57625 0.1935,1.35773 -0.29052,1.35773 -0.87317,1.8423 -0.77562,1.45475 -0.58211,1.84282 -1.64826,0.6786 -0.19403,1.35773 0,1.45475 0.87263,0.77615 -0.77562,1.06668 -0.29105,1.26071 -0.58212,1.16369 0.097,1.74581 -0.097,1.74581 -0.48456,1.55123 0.0901,1.69943 0.89769,0.84225 0.39341,0.78575 1.62746,0.56132 1.2911,-0.44938 0.89823,0.39341 0.28092,0.9542 -0.11247,1.06614 1.23512,0.3369 1.12265,-0.22442 0.67327,0.61729 -0.3369,1.0107 -0.22443,0.78575 0.39288,0.89823 -0.50482,1.29109 0.056,1.06668 0.9542,0.72977 0,1.57149 -0.16845,1.06668 0.28093,1.17862 0.39287,0.72977 -0.44938,1.51552 0.50535,1.23513 0.50535,1.01017 -0.3369,0.84225 0.56132,1.34707 0.50536,0.95419 -0.0565,1.2911 0.39341,1.23513 0.74523,1.05761 0.44885,1.12265 -0.056,1.06614 1.40358,1.17915 -0.0565,1.40304 1.2911,1.57149 0.89822,1.17916 0.72978,0.89822 0.72977,2.02034 0.84172,0.61783 0.6738,1.34707 0.11195,1.06614 -0.89769,1.628 -0.39341,1.01017 0.44938,1.85242 0.16845,1.51552 -0.56133,1.23512 -0.16845,1.51552 -0.39287,1.73995 0.2804,1.17862 -0.056,1.23512 -0.16845,1.73994 0.44885,1.628 0.6738,1.2911 1.17862,0.78574 0.89822,1.01017 2.30127,1.12265 -0.28039,0.89822 -0.89823,1.01017 -0.16845,1.12265 1.01017,1.01017 0.72977,0.28093 0.39288,1.01017 0.44938,1.0107 0.95419,0.67327 0.77082,0.94993 0,0.88863 1.35667,0.98245 -0.46804,1.07574 0.18711,1.49686 0.28093,1.12264 -0.60824,1.16903 0.18711,1.35666 0.32731,1.07574 -0.88863,0.65461 -0.37422,0.84225 0.18711,1.07574 0.60823,0.65461 -1.54377,0.60823 -0.93554,0.1402 -1.02882,0.88916 -0.98245,1.21594 -1.02883,1.26284 -0.46804,0.70152 -1.07573,1.21647 -0.98192,0.6077 -1.26284,0.0938 -0.23402,-1.02936 -0.23402,-0.74789 -0.84172,-0.32784 -1.07574,0.70152 -0.56132,0.88916 0.0464,1.26284 0.0938,1.26285 0.28039,0.42112 0.37422,1.02883 -0.1402,0.79534">
                        <title>East Godavari</title>
                    </path>
                </a>
                </g>
        </svg>
    </div>



    <div id="bottom" data-ng-view="">
        <!--
     This DIV loads templates depending upon route.
 -->
    </div>

</body>
```

Hii i found an issue when using angularjs ui routing .here ui routing is not working in firefox in few cases not working in crome v.49 so how to solve these kind of issues here is my plunker code https://plnkr.co/edit/hPbh2QjkkeVTAjW8Zsmc?p=preview not woking in firefox

Comment: even i found the same issue

Comment: That aint ui-router. Also, can you please explain what *"not working"* means in this instance?

Comment: hi @Phil Please can you run my Plunker in fire fox and click the image there so that once u click the image page get route to another page and it get scroll so i failed to achieve that

Comment: I'd say that's an issue with `<a>` tags in `<svg>` elements

Comment: @phil so how to solve my issue is there any alternate way to do that

Comment: @GOPALYADAV added an answer, please check it.

Answer (score 1):

[Working Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/PyVF13z838Wwt2ph5BBr?p=preview)

The problem is not related to angular `ui-route`. It's an issue with `<a>` tags in `<svg>` elements that already suggested by Phil. Add `xlink:` before `href` attribute. Also add `target="_self"` attribute in anchor tag.

```
<a xlink:href="#/EastGodavari" id="94650dac-e76b-4dec-8fcc-2d40dff7d95d" class="District" title="EastGodavari" target="_self">
```

If you want to use anchor tag in `svg`, [please read this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/a).

Hope that solve your problem.

Comment: Hi @Khalid Hussain your code is not working in chrome

Comment: Oops!  @Phani thank you. just wait, I will try......

Comment: Hi @Khalid Hussain its working fine in firefox but not in chrome

Comment: @GOPALYADAV Updated my answer. Now it's working on both Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Hi @Khalid Hussain really u done a great job